# Can anyone give me a really simple explanation of how transistors work?

Tags: transistors

I'm currently into electronics and learning about it as a whole. Does anyone think that they could explain transistors to a basic level. I've read lots of websites etc, but none if them make any sense to me! I'm looking to understand to what extend they activate and how to use them as a switch.

Comment: To the right of this page is the title 'Related' above a set of links to other parts of this site. There are several possible answers there. To help us, would you give links to some of the sites you've read, and try to explain what you don't understand? Otherwise we might waste time writing exactly the same explanations. Also, it is hard to do a better simple explanation than some books provide. Have you looked at any books, e.g. 'The Art of Electronics' by Horowitz and Hill?

Comment: You asking what the insides do? Or how to use a transistor? Remember there are many types of transistors so I'm going to assume you are talking about Bipolar Junction Transistors (BJTs).

Comment: Not FETs?   Bipolars?   The Horowitz and Hill style explanation, but without math, is my "How Transistors REALLY Work," based on Ebers-Moll Vbe viewpoint, not the more common Shockley alpha/beta viewpoint.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY desire? Just simple? Or simple - but physically correct? Remember A. Einstein: "Make explanations as simple as possible - BUT NOT SIMPLER"!!! In many books you can find very simple descriptions (which, however, are wrong). Start a searching action (also in THIS forum) - and you will find many questions/answers relevant to your problem. By the way: "The Art of Electronics" can be recommended.

Comment: There are a few different types of transitors, if you are interested in FETs, and the actual mechanics behind the device, I suggest looking on the  youtube channel 'veritasium' for how a transistor works. I wound id very helpful when trying to understand the actual movement of particles in the semiconductor crystal.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to understand to what extend they activate and how to use
>   them as a switch.

There are two basic types of transistor that are used as switches - bipolar (NPN, PNP) and field effect (MOSFET).

A bipolar transistor can be thought of as a *current amplifier* with a diode between Base and Emitter. If the transistor has a current gain (H<sub>FE</sub>) of eg. 100 then it can switch a current up to 100 times greater than what is fed into the Base. But (due to the Base-Emitter diode) as Base voltage is increased the input current will rise very rapidly once it gets past 0.6V, so you need a resistor to limit Base current. Current gain varies with temperature and Collector-Emitter voltage, so to guarantee that it will be switched on fully under all conditions you should provide more Base current than the nominal H<sub>FE</sub> would indicate.

In contrast, a MOSFET is turned on by *voltage* between the Gate and Drain. The Gate draws no current, but does have some capacitance which must be charged/discharged. Again the response is nonlinear, but with this type of transistor you just need to ensure that the Gate gets enough voltage to turn on. The datasheet usually provides graphs showing the relationship between input voltage and output current, but the exact response is hard to manufacture accurately and varies widely between individual units. Therefore it is best to assume the worst case and give it plenty. MOSFETs are often described as 'Logic Level' (4.5V Gate drive) or eg. '2.5V' which specifies the voltage required to guarantee that they will turn on fully.

Most electronics tutorials focus on the the physics of what goes on inside a transistor (electrons, holes, channel widths etc.) but you don't really need to know that stuff. Just read the device's datasheet and take note of how it responds to different stimuli. This information tells you what you *really* need to know - how a particular device is expected to work in an actual circuit. And examining the datasheet works with *any* device, even if you don't know what technology it uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a very basic idea to contextualize the stuff that you are reading. I can give that a little try, but you will really learn by reading books (Horowitz and Hill, also the ARRL Handbook has a great transistor section) and building (and simulating) circuits.

As I'm sure you've read, a transistor is a "nonlinear" component that has three leads (instead of two, like capacitors, resistors, and diodes). One lead is called either the gate or the base, depending on if it's a FET or a BJT (read bout the differences). This lead is special, because the current flowing into it (or the voltage drop between it and the drain, in the case of a FET) determines the properties of the material between the other two leads.

Transistors can be used for switching and amplifying signals. For example, a typical BJT with no current flowing into the base is in the "off" mode. That means I can drop a voltage across the other two leads and no current will flow between them. It's just an open circuit. Now imagine I hook up an LED in series with the other two leads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQYU9C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I can turn the LED on and off with a small amount of current applied to the base. That's because when current flows into the base, the properties of the material that separate the collector and emitter change, and they begin to conduct current. This current then lights up the LED. That's an example of a switching application. The current flowing into the base causes current to flow between collector and emitter, thus switching on the LED.

The other big application is amplification. It involves the more complicated aspects of a transistor, and I won't bother quoting textbooks here.

This is just a little overview to encourage you to keep reading. There's lots of resources out there. Build some circuits.

Comment: Hunter Akins - because you have mentioned "Horowitz/Hill": Are you aware that this book does NOT follow your explanation (.."when current flows into the base, the properties of the material that separate the collector and emitter change, and begin to conduct current.") ? In reality, it is not the "property of the material" that changes but the thickness of the depletion area in the pn region - caused by the base-emitter VOLTAGE!

Comment: I was basing my description on the description of BJTs in the ARRL Handbook. The Ebers-Moll equations relate base current to the collector current, so it's an easy model to grasp. I think physically you are right, it is the voltage that changes the properties. In any case,  the base-emitter voltage and current are related more or less by the Shockley diode equation. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes my explanation for the basic working principle of a bipolar transistor (BJT) - as simple as possible:

(1) Please, remember how a pn diode works: It is a non-linear element, which means, that the current does NOT primarily depends on the resistance of the material but on the thickness of the depletion area across the pn junction (the physical cause of this depletion area are diffusion effects between the p- and the n-region). The thickness of this area is controlled/determined by the applied external voltage. As a result, we have the known exponential I-V relationship (first described and explained by W. Shockley). A larger voltage across the diode causes a "shrinking" effect which allows rising of the current because the charged carriers (current) have more and more "movement energy" for crossing this depeletion area.

(2) This is also the basic working principle of the bipolar transistor. A change of the applied base-emitter voltage VBE influences the thickness of the depletion zone at the pn junction. As a consequence, the current is controlled by this voltage VBE (diode principle) - however, the majority of this current (more than 95%) goes to the collector (and NOT to the base node) because the charged carriers forming this current are strongly attracted by the relatively large collector voltage (much larger than the base voltage). In this context, it is important to know that the thickness of the depletion area is in µm range.

(3) As a first approximation, the amount of charged carriers reaching the collector (as an example, I have mentioned 95%) is INDEPENDENT on the collector-emitter voltage VCE (as long as it is larger than the base voltage). Hence, the collector current IC does not change much for variation of VCE (5V or 9V or 12V). 
Therefore, the BJT is usually described and handled as a "voltage-controlled current source".

Comment: As indicated by the downvoting, there must be someone who knows better.  Where is his answer? We should not leave the questioner alone with my - as it seems - wrong explanation.

Comment: I understand the downvote. The OP is an electronics newbie, and this will confuse him so much, even me. Depletion area... exponential relationship... VBE... It's unclear from a perspective that's new to this area (and even I haven't studied this). I think images and slow steps are the way to go, but that may make the answer really long. "I'm looking to understand to what extend they activate and how to use them as a switch." I don't think he wants an explanation of their internals, but rather how to use them.

Comment: Bradman - I understand your comment; however, when somebody asks how a BJT works - I think, at least I must assume that he has some basic knowledge about a pn junction diode. Otherwise, this forum is not the right place for such questions. But - may I ask YOU: WHAT WOULD BE YOUR ANSWER?

Comment: A. Einstein: "Explanations should be as simple as possible - BUT NOT simpler". I have tried to give an explanation as simple as possible (i think). Any furhter simplifications I have seen elsewhere (for example: steerable resistor) are - for my opinion - disadvantageous because they do not open the way to a good and correct understanding. Instead, they cause some sorts of misunderstandings/contradictions when newbies start to design their own circuits. In case my explanations are too challenging, I am sorry....but they reflect the physical truth.

Answer (score 0):

Germanium and Silicon are "semi-conductors". They can either conduct or insulate depending on small influences.  Much like undecided voters in an election.  You can inject a few electrons (NPN) or drain a few holes (PNP) through the base/gate and turn on or off the main current path.  Rather like "peer pressure" when you were back at school.